# PySide2 Cannot Find Qt_5.15

Tags: python, linux, docker, qt, pyside2

This Friday my PySide2 installation stopped working inside an Ubuntu 18.04 container (based on nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu18.04). I now get the following error:

```
python3 -c "from PySide2 import QtWidgets"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PySide2/libpyside2.abi3.so.5.15)
```

I have tried to manually compile Qt via

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install -y \
    clang \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libx11-dev \
    libxext-dev \
    libxfixes-dev \
    libxi-dev \
    libxrender-dev \
    libxcb1-dev \
    libx11-xcb-dev \
    libxcb-glx0-dev \
    libxkbcommon-x11-dev \
    libxcb-keysyms1-dev \
    libxcb-image0-dev \
    libxcb-shm0-dev \
    libxcb-icccm4-dev \
    libxcb-sync0-dev \
    libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
    libxcb-shape0-dev \
    libxcb-randr0-dev \
    libxcb-render-util0-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cd /tmp && wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.15/5.15.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz && \
    tar -xf qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz && tar -xf qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz && \
    rm qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz && cd qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0 && export QT5PREFIX=/opt/qt5 && \
    ./configure -prefix $QT5PREFIX \
            -sysconfdir /etc/xdg \
            -confirm-license \
            -opensource \
            -system-harfbuzz \
            -nomake examples \
            -no-rpath \
            -skip qtwebengine && \
    make && make install
```

(and added it to PATH) but that did not help (same error).

I tried with the default packages as well, i.e. `apt install qt5-default python3-pyside python3-pip`, but despite installing PySide the PySide2 module is not found, so I installed it via pip as well, i.e. `python3 -m pip install -U pip && python3 -m pip install PySide2`. But even then I hit the same issue again. At least here I understand it, because I installed Qt 5.9.5 by using the version in the repository.

Could someone help me with getting the import to run so I can again run PySide2 bindings like it worked mid last week? Thank you in advance.

**Appendix**
I have also tried creating a `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf` file with the content

```
/opt/qt5/bin
/opt/qt5/lib
```

to point to my manually compiled Qt, but to no avail.

UPDATE: I think this has to do with me compiling OMPL before compiling Qt which installs its own Qt version. So PySide2 then picks up the wrong version. However, I have been unable to point it to the right Qt version. Could someone recap which variables I need to set for this beyond what I have already mentioned? Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what I understand you want to use PySide2 5.15 and you have problems, have you tried using PySide2 5.14.2?

Comment: Good point. `python3 -m pip uninstall PySide2 && python3 -m pip install PySide2==5.14.2` changes the error to `ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.14' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PySide2/libpyside2.abi3.so.5.14)`. Seems like Qt is not properly registered. I also noticed that in my more complex image I seem to be missing `qtchooser`. Not sure why. Any idea which environment variables I should try setting in addition to PATH?

Comment: Have you tried on a ubuntu image (without nvidia)?. Note: do not install the system Qt since it can bring conflicts, PySide2 already comes with its own Qt

Comment: No, but my problem is that I need GPU acceleration and CUDA. Thus, if possible I'd like to stick with `nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu18.04`. I can try pure ubuntu for comparison, but that would be testing only.

Comment: My idea is to know who is causing the error, so I want to reduce the complexity, if it works in a docker without nvidia then the problem is caused by some component of that docker. Why don't you use a virtualenv? This way you could eliminate conflicts with OS libraries.

Comment: I have been able to build a working Docker container (with GPU support), but tracing back the issue in my question will take some additional time. I will report back once I've fully figured out what is going on. Thank you for your support - your input was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

move pyside2 imports top of other imports:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
# other imports
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem - pyside2 kept loading the 5.9.5 version of libQt5Core from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so even though my venv contained the correct 5.9.15 version. I added LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings to venv/bin/activate and my world suddenly got much better:
Immediately after the

```
# unset PYTHONHOME if set
```

section, I added

```
if [ -n "{LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}" ]; then
    LDLIB_PATHSEP=""
else
    LDLIB_PATHSEP=':'
fi
OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/lib/${LDLIB_PATHSEP}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Within the deactivate() definition, I also added code to restore any pre-activate LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
if [ -n "{OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}" ]; then
    unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
fi
```

P.S. Ubuntu 18.04; python 3.6; venv set up as:

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/venv_pyside2
$ ~/venv_pyside2/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped on Debian Bullseye. After a clean install of `PySide2`, the `pyside-designer` won't start unless this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set first.